# How to enter arrays of varried dimensions into a method in java

Tags: java, arrays

My java program formats data from a string array into a string and can basically pull an inception and store these strings along other strings of the same format, in a way making a 2D array but in a string format. My issue is for a 1D array I roughly have the following methods in a class...

```
public static String parse(String data) {
    return "#"+Integer.toString(data.length())+":"+data;
}
public static String parse(String[] data) {
    String str="";
    for (int i=1;i<=data.length;i++) {
        str+=parse(data[i-1]);//parse() would receive a String
    }
    return str;
}
```

My problem is I want to make a singular method that can take in an array of ANY dimensions, but the closest I can get to doing this is declaring multiple methods with the same name but with higher array dimensions set for the input variable 'data' like so...

```
public static String parse(String[][] data) {//can take in a 2D array
    String str="";
    for (int i=1;i<=data.length;i++) {
        str+=parse(data[i-1]);//parse() would receive a 1D array
    }
    return str;
}
public static String parse(String[][][] data) {//can take in a 3D array
    String str="";
    for (int i=1;i<=data.length;i++) {
        str+=parse(data[i-1]);//parse() would receive a 2D array
    }
    return str;
}
//etc...
```

Is there a way to work arround this? Or is this the best way to program it?

PS:I'm new to this language and still dont know a lot of terminology, so keep it simple please.

Comment: note you don't need to parse the length into an integer, you can simple do return "#"+data.length()+":"+data;

Comment: I don't really know what you're doing with parse since I can barely read your English but possibly you may have fun with `varargs`.

Comment: Try to use an ArrayList because it's a Colletion and have variable dimension so you can use it as an array, but you don't need to declare dimensions because you can Add how many elements you want.

Comment: You can use `Object[]` as the array's parameter type in one single method. After which you can use `instanceof` inside the method to decide whether its a `String[][]` or `String[][][]` & process the array accordingly. Kind of a hack really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the difference in types, 1 parse method takes a `String[][][]` and calls another `parse` method that takes a `String[][]`. That second call is different for each level, so you can't create 1 single method that works for all of them.

Something that you *can* do (but will be tricky to grasp for a beginner) is reduce some of the duplication. If you pass the next `parse` method to call as an argument to `parse`. You can then use lambdas to chain method calls together:

```
public static String parse0(String data) {
    return "#" + Integer.toString(data.length()) + ":" + data;
}

// Method that contains the real logic
private static <T> String parseInternal(T[] data, Function<T, String> parser) {
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        str += parser.apply(data[i]);
    }
    return str;
}

// Methods that provide the call chain:
public static String parse3(String[][][] data) {
    return parseInternal(data, arr2 -> parse2(arr2));
}

public static String parse2(String[][] data) {
    return parseInternal(data, arr -> parse1(arr));
}

public static String parse1(String[] data) {
    return parseInternal(data, str -> parse0(str));
}
```

Note: I gave all the methods a different name to show better what is going on. But you could give all of them the same name as well.

For more information about lambda expressions see the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is called recursion: that a method sometimes calls itself for doing some of its task:

```
public static String parse(Object data) {
    if (data instanceof String) {
        return "#" + Integer.toString(((String) data).length()) + ":" + data;
    }
    if (data instanceof Object[]) {
        String str = "";
        for (Object obj : (Object[]) data) {
            str += parse(obj);
        }
        return str;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot parse type " + data.getClass());
}
```

Now we may do for instance:

```
    System.out.println(parse("str"));
    System.out.println(parse(new String[] { "abc", "def" }));
    System.out.println(parse(new String[][] { { "gh", "ij" }, { "kl" } }));
    System.out.println(parse(new String[][][] { { { "mn" }, { "op", "qr", "st" }, { "uv" } } }));
```

This prints:

```
#3:str
#3:abc#3:def
#2:gh#2:ij#2:kl
#2:mn#2:op#2:qr#2:st#2:uv
```

In fact you can call it with a `String` array with any number of dimension.